# Angular12/rxjs/typescript: Observable does not complete (inner/nested subscriptions)

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I have two functions with nested subscriptions.

Desired behaviour:

1. Update User Data
2. if previous step successful -> Update User Icon
3. if previous step successful OR skipped/errored -> Done, just route with returned url

```js
foo(): void {
    this.httpHandler.updateUser(userData).subscribe(
        (successUserData) => this.uploadAvatar().subscribe(
            (url) => this.route.navigate(url) //finish, some routing based on result url;
        )
    )
}

//returns an url or '' if skipped
uploadAvatar(): Observable<string> {
    let subject = new Subject<string>();

    if (!skipFileUpload) {
        this.httpHandler.uploadImage(this.file).subscribe(
            (successData) => {          
                this.httpHandler.verifySomething(successData.id).subscribe(
                   (verifiedData) => 
                       if (verifiedData) 
                          subject.next(verifiedData.url)
                )
            }
        )
    } else {
        subject.next('');
    }

return subject.asObservable();
}
```

Problem:

If the file is not uploaded, the observable does not resolve. In other words: the `subject.next('');` does not work and my routing to '' does not happen.

However, if the upload occurs then everything works as expected

Can this whole procedure perhaps be flattened or simplified?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You have not written an error handler:

```
    uploadAvatar(): Observable<string> {
    let subject = new Subject<string>();

    if (!skipFileUpload) {
        this.httpHandler.uploadImage(this.file).subscribe(
            (successData) => {          
                this.httpHandler.verifySomething(successData.id).subscribe(
                   (verifiedData) => 
                       if (verifiedData) 
                          subject.next(verifiedData.url)
                )
            },
            // ****  you had not handled the error case
            (error) =>  { subject.next(); subject.complete(); }
        );
    } else {
        subject.next('');
       subject.complete(); // else it will ramin a hot obervable
    }

return subject.asObservable();
}
```

You can skip multiple subscribe by using 'concatMap' 'catchError' 'pipe'

Answer (score 0):

Instead of nesting multiple subscribes, you can use pipe to flatten it. I modified the the code based on your desired behavior.

*First* is we update the user data. *Next*, based on the code you posted, we will have a condition if we skip file upload, if no, we call the upload Image api call. *Then*, we call the verifySomething api call if the upload image call is successful. *Lastly*, when all are successful, we route to the url return from verifySomething url.

**Note**: I added the condition to check on the response param if there is a url property since we might get a response without url when we skip the uploadImage api call.

```
updateProfile(): void {
 this.httpHandler
  .updateUser(userData)
  .pipe(
    mergeMap((e) => {
      if (!skipFileUpload) {
        return this.httpHandler.uploadImage(this.file).pipe(
          mergeMap((successData) => {
            this.httpHandler.verifySomething(successData.id);
          })
        );
      } else {
        return of(e);
      }
    }),
    catchError((err) => {
      console.error(err);
      throw err;
    })
  )
  .subscribe((res) => {
    if (res && res.url) {
      this.route.navigate(res.url);
    }
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use switchMap to solve this.

```js
foo(): void {
    this.httpHandler.updateUser(userData).pipe(
      switchMap(() => this.uploadAvatar())
    ).subscribe((url) => this.route.navigate(url))
}

//returns an url or '' if skipped
uploadAvatar(): Observable<string> {
    let subject = new Subject<string>();

    if (!skipFileUpload) {
        const sub = this.httpHandler.uploadImage(this.file).pipe(
          switchMap((successData) => this.httpHandler.verifySomething(successData.id))
          tap((verifiedData) => subject.next(verifiedData ? verifiedData.url : ''))
          catchError(e => { subject.next(''); return throwError(e) })
        ).subscribe();
    } else {
        subject.next('');
    }

return subject.asObservable();
}
```

*In `uploadAvatar`, subscriptions should be managed properly.*

If you are using `updateAvatar` function only in `foo` then you can skip the extra function.

```js
foo(): void {
    this.httpHandler.updateUser(userData).pipe(
      map(() => skipFileUpload ? throwError('') : this.httpHandler.uploadImage(this.file))
      switchMap(obs => obs),
      map(successData => (successData && successData.id) ? this.httpHandler.verifySomething(successData.id) : throwError('')),
      switchMap(obs => obs),
      map(verifiedData => verifiedData ? of(verifiedData) : throwError('')),
      switchMap(obs => obs),
      catchError(err => { this.route.navigate(url); return throwError(err); })
    )
    ).subscribe((url) => this.route.navigate(url))
}
```